# GKE adding nodes to a cluster that are of different sizes

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

Why do you have this restriction on having each replica in a cluster be of the same machine-size? What if I want to add larger nodes four cores up from 2, or nodes with more RAM? In a more general sense, why heterogeneous kubernetes cluster is restricted on GKE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have heterogenous clusters with different machine types on GKE by creating node pools with the "--machine-type" option. For example:

```
gcloud container node-pools create $pool-name --cluster=$cluster-name --machine-type=n1-standard-4
```

This blog post explains some of the scenarios you can do with them, including creating pools with custom machine types: https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2016/05/introducing-Google-Container-Engine-GKE-node-pools.html

Hope this helps.

Edit: Just noticed the question mentioned GCE, and not just GKE. On GCE, the setup scripts only create a single managed instance group (MIG) with a fixed machine configuration. To add nodes of different types, you can clone the instance group template used, modify the machine type, then create a new managed instance group. Resize it to your desired size. The new nodes should be able to join your cluster, giving you the desired heterogenous configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly add nodes of different sizes to a cluster, it just isn't easy to do using `kube-up.sh`. It might be possible to do this by changing the machine types in `config-default.sh` and then re-running `kube-up.sh` setting `KUBE_USE_EXISTING_MASTER=true` but I haven't tested to see if this actually works (that variable was adding to support [multi-zone clusters](http://blog.kubernetes.io/2016/03/building-highly-available-applications-using-Kubernetes-new-multi-zone-clusters-a.k.a-Ubernetes-Lite.html) but may also allow you to create heterogenous clusters in a single zone).